# Error when copying a binary file with ifsream and stringstream

Tags: c++, file-io, stringstream, carriage-return, file-copying

I'm attempting to strip the header from an image file which contains a plain text header followed by binary image information. As a precursor to this I would like to copy the files information into a stringstream for editing. When doing this I encountered some issues which led me to try simply reading in the file and writing it back out again as a new file for debugging purposes. When I did this the new file ended up being about 1kb larger than the original. When doing a binary compare in UltraEdit it seems that anywhere the HEX character 0A (Line Feed I believe) appears my program seems to have added in 0D(carriage return) right before it. I was wondering what the cause of this behaviour was and how to avoid it if possible. Code snippet follows:

```
....
std::string inputFilename = argv[1];
std::ifstream in( argv[1],ios::out | ios::binary);
if ( in )
{
std::stringstream fileStream;
fileStream<<in.rdbuf();
cout<<fileStream.str().length(); //debugging
in.close();
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("selfoutput");
myfile<<fileStream.str();
myfile.close();
....
```

Thanks for any help!
-David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ios:in`

```
std::ifstream in( argv[1],ios::in | ios::binary)
```

Or, in fact

```
std::ifstream in( argv[1],ios::binary)
```

Which is equivalent:

> First, performs the same steps as the default constructor, then asssociates the stream with a file ***by calling `rdbuf()->open(filename, mode | std::ios_base::in)`***.. If the open() call returns a null pointer, sets 
>   setstate(failbit)

Here's my (untested) simplist take on it:

```
#include <fstream>

int main(int /*argc*/, const char *argv[])
{
    std::ifstream in(argv[1], std::ios::binary);
    if (in)
    {
        std::ofstream myfile("selfoutput", std::ios::binary);
        if (myfile)
            myfile << in.rdbuf();
    }
}
```

In the interest of gratuitous code golf and bad style:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int /*argc*/, const char *argv[]) {
    ofstream("selfoutput", ios::binary) << ifstream(argv[1], ios::binary).rdbuf();
}
```

Comment: the flag is on the `std::ifstream`. However, it is missing from the `std::ofstream`'s 'open()'.

Comment: Mmm. I hand't come that far. My point is, he's opening the ifstream for output...

Comment: he is opening the `std::ifstream` for both input and output. That doesn't make particular sense but isn't the actual problem. The actual problem is _not_ opening the `std::ofstream` with the `std::ios_base::binary` option.

Comment: Thanks sehe and @Dietmar ! Combining these fixes seems to have worked.

Comment: Also you're right about the ifstream being opened for input and output being a mistake...the dangers of cannibalizing code! Thanks again